# Not able to open python idle

Tags: python, installation

I have installed python and extracted all zip file including application extensions but when I click on application it show that application extension was missing , i tried many times by reinstalling but it didn't work. although that application extension is there extracted. I ask my friend and he said maybe program was not able to identify the path for extension. and I don't know how to change the path.
if that's the case please tell me how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean with "extracted all zip file including application extensions"? It's unclear what zip file you're talking about. The Python installer should do everything for you. On which operating system did you install which version of Python (from https://www.python.org/downloads/) and how?

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed Python from [python.org](https://www.python.org). There are multiple ways to download it. The easiest way, which you didn't seem to do, is click on the download button at the top of the download page, then simply run the file. (I'm going to assume you're using Windows, if not click the link that corresponds to your OS.) Another tip, I recommend checking the 'add to PATH' box in the installer. Otherwise, you might run into issues when running Python from the terminal. Good luck with it!